# Keep LaunchScreen While WkWebview Load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit, wkwebview

I am making an iOS Webview App with WkWebview.
and my app has own theme color (gray).
So my launchscreen and web site's background is all gray.
But there is a problem.

My App screen color becomes white between launchscreen end and webview load.

Q1.
Is there a solution that can keep launch screen while webview load?

Q2.
Or is there a solution that can change WkWebview load background color white to gray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can create your own splash screen controller and dismiss it once webview finishes loading.

**Step 1** - On `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method create a splashviewController and make it main `rootviewController` of `window`.

**Step 2** - Start loading URL in web view and add `delegate` callbacks to find out webpage finished loading.

**Step 3** - Remove Splash controller from the window and make `webviewController` as `rootController`

Hope this clears your doubt. If not let me know

Answer (score 0):

A1. As I know there is no such solution.

A2. You can put your WkWebView on another view (with gray background) and make WkWebView transparent as shown below. So your WkWebView will be transparent until the webpage will not be loaded.

I hope this will help.

```
wkWebview.isOpaque = false
wkWebview.backgroundColor = .clear


//wkWebview.superview?.backgroundColor = .gray//to set background color of superview
```

Comment: Just setting the `backgroundColor` to the colour you desire (not clear) but still setting `isOpaque = false` removed the white flash for me.

Answer (score 0):

//Xcode13

```
webView.isOpaque = false; 
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
```